# Python: Search for a list of nested dict in a list of nested dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, nested

Let's say we have:

```
stack = [
         {'id': '1', 'name': {'firstname': 'bob', 'lastname': 'smith'}},
         {'id': '2', 'name': {'firstname': 'jane', 'lastname': 'abb'}},
         {'id': '3', 'name': {'firstname': 'flo', 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}},
         {'id': '4', 'name': {'firstname': 'frank', 'lastname': 'glow'}, 'partner': 'diane'}
]
needles = [{'name':{'lastname': 'gram'}},
          {'partner': 'diane'}
]
```

We'd like a function find, like so:

```
list = find(needles, stack)
print(list)
>[{id: '3', name: {firstname: 'flo', lastname: 'gram', middle: 'remi'}}, {id: '4', name: {firstname: 'frank', lastname: 'glow'}, partner: 'diane'}]
```

At first I wanted to use items(), like so:

```
def find(needle, stack):
    result = []
    for needle in needles:
        for item in stack:
            if needle.items() <= item.items():
                result.append()
```

But this returns:

```
[{'id': '4', 'name': {'firstname': 'frank', 'lastname': 'glow'}, 'partner': 'diane'}]
```

Because the item match has to be exact, I would have to pass `['name': {'firstname': 'flo', 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}, {'partner': 'diane'}'` for my function to return the desired result.

I am not sure where to go from here. Since my stack can be nested for an unknown depth ({a:{b:{c:value}}}) the solution might be some sort of recursion but it might not be necessary since I want to check for the exact 'path' (keys) in needle. It comes down to partially match needle items with stack items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def find(n, s):
   def exists(n, d):
      if type(n) != type(d):
         return False
      if not isinstance(n, (dict, list)):
          return n == d
      if isinstance(n, list):
          return any(exists(j, k) for j in n for k in d)
      return all(exists(b, d.get(a, None)) for a, b in n.items())
   return [i for i in s if any(exists(j, i) for j in n)]

stack = [{'id': '1', 'name': {'firstname': 'bob', 'lastname': 'smith'}}, {'id': '2', 'name': {'firstname': 'jane', 'lastname': 'abb'}}, {'id': '3', 'name': {'firstname': 'flo', 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}}, {'id': '4', 'name': {'firstname': 'frank', 'lastname': 'glow'}, 'partner': 'diane'}, {'id': '5', 'name': {'firstname': ['flo', 'Flo'], 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}}]
needles = [{'name': {'lastname': 'gram'}}, {'partner': 'diane'}, {'name':{'firstname':['Flo']}}]
results = find(needles, stack)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '3', 'name': {'firstname': 'flo', 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}}, 
 {'id': '4', 'name': {'firstname': 'frank', 'lastname': 'glow'}, 'partner': 'diane'}, 
 {'id': '5', 'name': {'firstname': ['flo', 'Flo'], 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}}]
```

Comment: That was fast! Yes, this is great. Could I modify this to also handle lists? aka if in the stack I have "{'id': '3', 'name': {'firstname': ['flo', 'Flo'], 'lastname': 'gram', 'middle': 'remi'}}" I would match it with a needle {name:{firstname:['Flo']}} ?